# Why does' PHP's str_replace() cause encoding issues?

Tags: php, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a string that I am passing through `str_replace()` , and it seems to have some effect on encoding that I cannot figure out.

example:

```
$str = "joined nearly 500 of the world’s investors .."; //shorted exceprt
$str = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

gives:

```
joined nearly 500 of the worldÂ’s investors
```

any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: You have a smart quote rather than a standard apostrophe.

Comment: Are you sure it's your PHP acting up? Is your HTML file properly configured for the encoding?

Comment: use `utf8_encode` in this certain case

Answer (score 2):

In your input, you have a smart quote that is not in its entity! Plus, you probably want to use UTF-8 so try this:

```
$str = "joined nearly 500 of the world’s investors .."; //shorted exceprt
$str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$str = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with `str_replace` or PHP, but rather HTML/browser charset encoding.

You can either do (in PHP, before anything else):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Or (in the `head` section of your HTML - HTML 5 here):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Another alternative would be to change your browsers default encoding.